# What steps to follow before pushing a Rails app to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a very simple app with almost no Ruby code, no database, just a single page with html, css, jquery, and a simple contact form. Still, pushing to Heroku is, as usual, just a bitch. It seems random what elements are working each time I try to push. First I got an error. Then the stylesheets didn't get included. Then the images and Fontawesome. Now both of those are working but not any Javascript/jQuery.

What are the actual steps I need to perform before pushing, because this is a crapshoot as it is. I'm basically just running precompile randomly and then trying to upload again, and each time something different gets uploaded.

Something funny though, when I run a `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` I get the same error as I did the first time I tried to push to Heroku (but I don't get that error anymore when I push):

```
rake aborted!
ExecJS::ProgramError: Name expected (line: 15546, col: 4, pos: 453566)

Error
at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20150126-3561-i1rcaljs:2359:10623)
at js_error (/tmp/execjs20150126-3561-i1rcaljs:2359:10842)
at croak (/tmp/execjs20150126-3561-i1rcaljs:2359:19086)
at as_symbol (/tmp/execjs20150126-3561-i1rcaljs:2359:29188)
at vardefs (/tmp/execjs20150126-3561-i1rcaljs:2359:25758)
at var_ (/tmp/execjs20150126-3561-i1rcaljs:2359:25996)
at /tmp/execjs20150126-3561-i1rcaljs:2359:21785
at /tmp/execjs20150126-3561-i1rcaljs:2359:19957
at block_ (/tmp/execjs20150126-3561-i1rcaljs:2359:24599)
at ctor.body (/tmp/execjs20150126-3561-i1rcaljs:2359:24233)
(in /home/my_name/Desktop/rails/bsun/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)/home/my_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:64:in `extract_result'
```

So how am I supposed to troubleshoot that exactly? Line 15546 of WHAT?

Here are the things I've had to troubleshoot and add since my first failed attempt to push:

1. Added `gem 'pg'` in production despite not having a database.
2. Added `config.assets.compile = true` and `config.serve_static_assets = true` in production.rb.
3. Ran `rake assets:precompile` a dozen times.
4. Ran `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` unsuccessfully.

What more do I have to do to push a simple page to Heroku?

**Edit:** The answer below is a great one, I just thought I'd add some details in case anyone is as unskilled as me and having similar problems.

1. Letting Heroku handle all precompiling is a great tip. DON'T touch the settings regarding handling static assets or whatever in production.rb no matter how many people suggest it in various other threads here on SO. I mean, I'm sure it's good for something and for people who know what they're doing, but listening to those people got me into a lot of trouble. If you follow their advice, you have to follow an entirely different set of steps when deploying.
2. If you get an error like me (ExecJS::ProgramError: Name) you can ignore what follows it and simply open the Javascript console on your page in your browser (Ctrl-Shift-J for Chrome) and check if it returns any errors. In my case, it did, but even if it doesn't removing Javascript code block by block and then running RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile locally is a good way of troubleshooting it. I had a comma instead of a semi-colon that somehow made the code work in the browser but threw an error in the console as well as when precompiling it. Also, don't forget to revert back to before you precompiled or run RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:clean before deploying to Heroku.
3. I fixed my background images not showing up by changing the scss syntax to background: image-url('name-of-img.png') from background: url('name-of-img') and somehow, magically, it worked.

Phew!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd say that you probably don't need rails for this, you could likely get away with a static website, which can be created using tools like [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com) for instance.

If you do want to use rails and heroku though, there are some things Heroku requires (and will inject into your application should it lack them). The docs state that you need to have your app configured to use postgreSQL, so I suppose you need the postgres gem.

To serve the static assets, simply add the `12factor` gem: `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production`.

This way you can remove the `config.serve_static_assets` configuration option and things should work.

The asset pipeline and Heroku has been a source of confusion for many, and I've found that the easiest way to get it working is to simply **let Heroku fix the asset compilation for you**. So don't run `rake assets:precompile` locally first, just let Heroku handle that (which they do as part of their deployment when you push your code to their repository). So, set `config.assets.compile = false` instead.

I'd also suggest following the steps outlined in the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4) for working with rails and the cedar stack.

First, create your Heroku application using the Heroku Command Line Client (`heroku create`) and then run `git push heroku master` and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, when I install that gem and set `config.assets.compile` and `config.serve_static_assets` to false neither images nor Fontawesome icons get installed on the page. Not to mention Javascript/jQuery, but I've never managed to get that installed.

Comment: I reverted back to a previous version and deleted my app and created a new and started fresh. Now the problem is that error I mentioned in my OP, except with slightly different numbers. `ExecJS::ProgramError: Name expected (line: 15531, col: 4, pos: 453127)`. I have no idea how to troubleshoot that. I don't know which file I'm supposed to look in.

Comment: How are you using Font Awesome? Are you using a CDN, a gem, or have you downloaded the specific files and added them to your public folder?

Comment: It's all fixed now. I added an edit to your comment with some details but I'm not sure that is the SO way of doing things so please forgive me if it isn't.